# RDLC Report table output show outside the table and unorganized

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, rdlc

i am using .net framework 4.5 and try it with 4.6 same problem in my main project
i also use visual studio 2017

so when i try to creat table in my report file *.rdlc the output go outside, whene simple text reamain in design position, my form using scale mode DPI and evrything on default, i populate the repport like this :

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select name from Product", connection);
DataSet1 set = new DataSet1();
sda.Fill(set, "Product");
ReportDataSource dataSource = new ReportDataSource(REPORT_DATASET_NAME,set.Tables[0]);
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(dataSource);
reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

so DataSet1 is one table Product with one column name,
wherever i dont have probleme with data i have only bad output organisation,

remark : i try it with new project it work fine and also try to recreat all classes that involve repport from scratch with only default setting and simple exemple like this, same problem.

output that i have :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i found when some form that is inside another form and try to call third form in my case the form with ReportViewer attach to it so when i have this chain Form1->Form2->FormReportViewer somehow the design becom unorganized so what i did to fix this problem Form1->Form2->Trigger Event In Form1->Form1 Open FormReportViewer and the outup is exactly like i designed so this question is still open because i dont know what cause this problem in multi form call wherever if you have this same problem maybe you find this answer usfeul